# Memory issues with two dimensional array

Tags: c++, memory, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

Following [this nice example](http://www.cs.csustan.edu/~john/Classes/General_Info/dynamic_C++_Array_Help.html) I found, I was trying to create a function that dynamically generates a 2D grid (two dimensional array) of `int` values.

It works fairly well the first couple of times you change the values but if crashes after that. I guess the part where memory is freed doesn't work as it should.

```
void testApp::generate2DGrid() {
    int i, j = 0;

    // Delete previous 2D array
    // (happens when previous value for cols and rows is 0)
    if((numRowsPrev != 0) && (numColumnsPrev != 0)) {
        for (i = 0; i < numRowsPrev; i++) {
            delete [ ] Arr2D[i];
        }
    }

    // Create a 2D array
    Arr2D = new int * [numColumns];
    for (i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        Arr2D[i] = new int[numRows];
    }

    // Assign a random values
    for (i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
            Arr2D[i][j] = ofRandom(0, 10);
        }
    }

    // Update previous value with new one
    numRowsPrev = numRows;
    numColumnsPrev = numColumns;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2-dim array in C++ with no memory issues:

```
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> Array;
typedef std::vector<Array> TwoDArray;
```

Usage:

```
TwoDArray Arr2D; 

// Add rows
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
    Arr2D.push_back(Array());
}

// Fill in test data
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {    
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        Arr2D[i].push_back(ofRandom(0, 10));           
    }
}

// Make sure the data is there
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {    
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        std::cout << Arr2D[i][j] << ' ';
    }
std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You are using C++ not C use the standard library it saves you from the sort of problems you have in your question.

Comment: Quick comment. After // Make sure the data is there you should replace 5 by numRows and 10 by numCols

Answer (score 5):

I see 1 major bug:

```
// Assign a random values
for (i=0; i<numRows; i++){
    for (j=0; j<numColumns; j++){
        Arr2D[i][j] = ofRandom(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Here the variable 'i' is used as the first index into 'Arr2D' and goes to a max of (numRows -1)
While in this code:

```
for (i=0; i<numColumns; i++)
{
    Arr2D[i] = new int[numRows];
}
```

The variable 'i' is used as the first index but goes to a max of (numColumns-1). If numRows is much larger than numColumns then we are going to have a problem.

As a side note. When you try and clean up you are leaking the columns:

```
if((numRowsPrev != 0) && (numColumnsPrev != 0))
{
    for (i=0; i<numRowsPrev; i++){
        delete [ ] Arr2D[i];
    }
    // Need to add this line:
    delete [] Arr2D;
}
```

Next thing to note.
This is truly not a good idea. Use some of the provided STL classes (or potentially boost Matrix). This looks like you are binding global variables and all sorts of other nasty stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give the other answer as valid because it looks like the best solution but I wish I could tick both as you spent time finding where the problem is.